# Vertically center content added using :after and "content" property

Tags: css

See this css:

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
div:after {
  content: "test";
  height: 100px;

}
```

I'm trying to vertically center the content of `div:after`. How can I do that?

I cannot set `line-height` to `px` value as height of the `div` might be dynamic (`height: 100px` is just for this example, in my app it stretches according to it's content)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ELnsJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS translate.

See pen: http://codepen.io/jhealey5/pen/Jseyt

```
    div {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background: #333;
      color: #fff;
      position: relative;
    }
    div:after {
      position: absolute;
      content: "test";
      margin-top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
```

Comment: I do like this solution as it doesn't include any layout changes as `display:table` does

Answer (score 1):

Using `display:table-cell` you can make it vertically align middle.

```
div:after {
content: "test";
height: 100px;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this](http://codepen.io/tusharbandal/pen/duowb)

CSS

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  display: table;
}
div:after {
  content: "test";
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AQMPg/)**

**CSS:**

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  display:table;

}
div:after {
  content: "test";
  height: 100px;
  display:table-cell;
   vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center;

}
```